# Adding font awesome icon inline yet superscript with other element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have two scenarios with similar problems. I'm attempting to add a font awesome icon:

1. Inline with a text input and 'add on' button, yet superscript ([JSFiddle1](https://jsfiddle.net/spencerkier/b3oewudp/))

```html
<div>
  <div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" id="copy-link" type="button">
      <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i> Copy
    </button>
  </span>
  </div>
  <span>
  <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

2. Inline with text in a bootstrap panel heading text, but in the top right corner of the heading area ([JSFiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/spencerkier/2uw3r8z5/))

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <b>
      Text
    </b>
    <span>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-cog dropdown-toggle listing-cog" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></i>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's how I'd like each to look:

1. [image]
2. [image]

I don't know if this is important, but as a side note:

1. In the first scenario, the icon has a popover
2. In the second scenario, the icon has a dropdown

I don't think these have any effect on the layout, so I left out the related code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first issue: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b3oewudp/8/)

For your second issue as Raed N. said before just add a float:right to your dropdown:

```
.dropdown {  float:right; }
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

For the first problem, your HTML structure is wrong. You need to add the icon inside the input-group DIV. Also to do superscript, you need a CSS class for that. Here is the update code for you:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b3oewudp/2/)

For your second problem, your DIV must be displayed inline with a flotation. Here is the CSS for it:

```
.dropdown {
  display:inline-block;
  float:right
}
```

Comment: Adding the icon to the input-group breaks the styling of it for one thing, see the disconnect between the button and form input in your example compared to the question and the [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons).